# C sockets on windows, randomly getting recv errors but errno is at 0?

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I have a client and a server using sockets on windows. I start the server before the client, wait for it to hang and then start the client. Doing so, the call to `recv()` will randomly (half of the time) return -1 and when I print errno it is at 0 (No Error)... The other half of the time it will receive the message and print it normally then close... Is there something wrong with this code ?

**client.c**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 200

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);
    
    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    // address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    InetPton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &address.sin_addr.s_addr);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(8888);
    
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("Erreur lors de la création du socket. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((connect(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&address, sizeof(address))) == -1) {
        sprintf("Erreur lors de la connexion au socket. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *msg = "Coucou\n";
    printf("Envoi de coucou\n");
    int bytesSent;

    if ((bytesSent = send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0)) == -1) {
        sprintf("Erreur lors l'envoi du message. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Bytes envoyés : %d\n", bytesSent);

    WSACleanup();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**server.c**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BACKLOG 3 // taille de la file d'attente
#define BUFFER_LEN 200 // taille du buffer de lecture

int main()
{
    WSADATA WSAData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &WSAData);
    
    SOCKET sockfd;
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    // address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(8888); // host to network short (conversion de host byte order en network byte order)
    
    printf("Démarrage du serveur\n");

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("Erreur lors de la création du socket. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((bind(sockfd, (SOCKADDR *)&address, sizeof(address))) == -1) {
        printf("Erreur lors de l'ouverture du socket. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((listen(sockfd, BACKLOG)) == -1) {
        printf("Erreur lors de l'écoute du socket. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    SOCKET clientSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN clientAddress;
    int addrLen = sizeof(clientAddress);
    if ((clientSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &addrLen)) == -1) {
        printf("Erreur lors de l'acceptation de la connexion. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Convertion de l'IP en texte
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(clientAddress.sin_addr), ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Connexion de %s:%i\n", ip, clientAddress.sin_port);

    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    int len = recv(clientSocket, buffer, BUFFER_LEN, 0);

    if (len == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) {
        printf("Erreur lors de la réception du message. %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (len == 0) {
        printf("Le client s'est déconnecté (extrémité de la socket fermée)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (len > 0) {
        printf("Message reçu : %s\n", buffer);
    }

    closesocket(clientSocket);
    closesocket(sockfd);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

I also should mention that I compile with `gcc main.c -lws2_32 -g -Wall`

Comment: I don't have Windows to test this on, but your client sends some data and then immediately exits (without closing the socket). Maybe that is destroying the socket before it has actually sent the data. Maybe adding a `close()` or a delay would fix it.

Comment: [Quote:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) *Otherwise, a value of SOCKET_ERROR is returned, and a specific error code can be retrieved by calling [WSAGetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror)*

Comment: That was it @pmacfarlane, thanks. You can post this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you also Hans, I'll try this out.

Comment: On a side note, there is no `EAGAIN` on Windows. If a non-blocking socket (and FYI, you are not using non-blocking sockets) encounters a blocking operation, `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` is reported.

Comment: Thank you, this all makes sense now. It seems that making native sockets cross platform is a real challenge. I'll stick to the Windows documentation now and stop mixing UNIX tutorials with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to note is that when the call to `send()` in your client returns, this does *not* mean that any data has been sent to your server. It just means the data has been queued up to be sent.

Your client then immediately calls `WSACleanup()` and exits. It would appear that this just instantly destroys your socket, before it has had a chance to send anything.

You should add `closesocket(sock)` between sending your data, and calling `WSACleanup()`. This will allow the socket to be closed in an orderly manner, including flushing any data that has been queued up.

As pointed out by @Hans, reading `errno` is not the correct way to get a socket error, you should use [WSAGetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsagetlasterror).